# MySQLDump Backup of UTF-8 Database Has Character Corruption, But Default Charsets are Correct

Tags: mysql, utf-8

When I'm trying to make a full dump of the database as follows:

`mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -uUSER -p database -r output.sql`

It creates a UTF-8 file but all international data (Chineese,Spanish,Russian) is corrupted as follows(it's Russian part of the dump):

`(1,'Ð<9e> Ð½Ð°Ñ<81>')`

However, when I try to dump one table, it works fine: 
`mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -uUSER -p database table_name -r output.sql`

I don't quite understand what causes the issue as all possible variables are set to UTF-8:

```
show variables like "collation_database";
+--------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name      | Value           |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| collation_database | utf8_general_ci | 
+--------------------+-----------------+

show variables like "character_set_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  | 
+------------------------+-------+
```

All tables also have the same charset/collation.
There are the following settings in my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

And finally, locale is set to utf-8 as well.
So what could be the problem of the issue? I'm pretty sure it's a dumb issue but I'm out of the ideas. I would appreciate the assistance greatly.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem and I'm screwed.

Comment: That's "Mojibake". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword -c -e --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction --skip-set-charset --add-drop-database -B dbname > dump.sql
```

Then in shell copy and edit

```
shell> cp dump.sql dump-fixed.sql
shell> vi or vim dump-fixed.sql
:%s/DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1/DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci/
:%s/DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1/DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8/
```

then save the file

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this tremendously, and tried many online solutions I 've found, such as `--default-character-set=utf8` or `iconv` or `vim setfileencoding=utf8`, and none of these worked!  It was even more frustrating, because I could select properly formatted data in the database itself, and I could select the encoding vars which were all in UTF-8.  Anyway!

### TLDR Solution:

1. Create the dump as normaly, *except* with **`-default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset`**.
2. Do a manual find/replace of "latin1" with `"utf8"` (or `"utf8mb3"`, which is just an alias, so, use either).

### Full Code Solution:

```
mysqldump
-u username -pPASSWORD
-h mysql.example.com
--default-character-set=latin1
--skip-set-charset
--no-tablespaces
-N
--routines
--skip-triggers
DATABASENAME > OUTPUTFILE.sql
```

Or, in one line:

```
mysqldump -u username -pPASSWORD -h mysql.example.com --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset --no-tablespaces -N --routines --skip-triggers DATABASENAME > OUTPUTFILE.sql
```

### Essential Code Explanation:

- `--default-character-set=latin1` and `--skip-set-charset`: This stops MySQL from trying to do any actual reconversion of the data, which can break things.
- `--no-tablespaces`: This resolves an [ACCESS-Denied Error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/271981/241842) caused by a MySQL bug.
- `--skip-triggers`: Skip doing triggers, but you may need this if you use them.

### How Did the Backup Work?  Test It:

To restore a dump, simply do in the MySQL prompt:

```
mysql> create database ExampleDB;
mysql> use ExampleDB;
mysql> source ExampleDB-backup.sql;
```